# Manifest attribute in Android using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new in android programming and I encountered some error while following some tutorials on Youtube.

`Manifest attribute 'minSdkVersion' is set to 'R'. Integer is expected.`

Here's the code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here's the AndroidManifest.xml
[image: AndroidManifest.xml]|
[image: .xml]
Again Im just a beginner, please help thanks!

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for several years now. [tag:android-studio] is what you should be using. Any tutorial that uses Eclipse is out of date.

Comment: do share your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: @greg-449 oh okay thanks!

Comment: @PriyankaRajput i added it

Comment: Do add xml file's code

Comment: @PriyankaRajput then?

Comment: I mean share your AndroidManifest.xml file's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change minSdkVersion version as below

```
android:minSdkVersion="21"
```